# How to validate Java parameters in wrapper.conf

Tags: java, jvm, jboss7.x, java-service-wrapper

I have using the following parameters in wrapper.conf in my JBoss_EAP_7.1.5 :

```
wrapper.java.additional.1=-Dprogram.name=JBoss_EAP_7.1.5
wrapper.java.additional.2=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.client.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.3=-Dsun.rmi.dgc.server.gcInterval=3600000
wrapper.java.additional.4=-Xms5G
wrapper.java.additional.5=-Xmx5G
wrapper.java.additional.6=-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
wrapper.java.additional.7=-Dsun.lang.ClassLoader.allowArraySyntax=true
wrapper.java.additional.8=-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true
wrapper.java.additional.9=-server
wrapper.java.additional.10=-XX:+UseParNewGC
wrapper.java.additional.11=-XX:NewRatio=10
wrapper.java.additional.12=-Djboss.platform.mbeanserver
wrapper.java.additional.13=-Dorg.eclipse.emf.ecore.EPackage.Registry.INSTANCE=org.eclipse.emf.ecore.impl.EPackageRegistryImpl
#Below parameter is added to support emptySessionPath in mod_jk connector
wrapper.java.additional.14=-Dorg.apache.catalina.connector.Request.SESSION_ID_CHECK=true
#Below parameter is added to support acceptCount in JBoss EAP
wrapper.java.additional.15=-Dorg.apache.tomcat.util.net.WAITFORWORKER=true
wrapper.java.additional.16=-Dorg.jboss.resolver.warning=true 
wrapper.java.additional.17=-Djboss.modules.system.pkgs=org.jboss.byteman,org.aspectj 
wrapper.java.additional.18=-Djava.awt.headless=true 
wrapper.java.additional.19=-Dorg.jboss.boot.log.file=..\standalone\log\boot.log
wrapper.java.additional.20=-Dlogging.configuration=file:..\standalone\configuration\logging.properties
wrapper.java.additional.21=-Dorg.jboss.logmanager.nocolor=true
wrapper.java.additional.22=-Djava.ext.dirs=..\jdk\jre\lib\ext;..\modules\org\aspectj\main
wrapper.java.additional.23=-javaagent:..\modules\org\aspectj\main\aspectjweaver-1.8.9.jar
wrapper.java.additional.24=-Dorg.aspectj.tracing.enabled=false 
wrapper.java.additional.25=-Dorg.aspectj.tracing.factory=default 
wrapper.java.additional.26=-Dorg.apache.activemq.SERIALIZABLE_PACKAGES=*
wrapper.java.additional.27=-XX:+PrintGCDetails
wrapper.java.additional.28=-XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
wrapper.java.additional.29=-Xloggc:C://xxxx_gc.log
wrapper.java.additional.30=-XX:PermSize=512m
wrapper.java.additional.31=-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=128m
wrapper.java.additional.32=-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled
wrapper.java.additional.33=-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
wrapper.java.additional.34=-XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=85
wrapper.java.additional.35=-XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly
wrapper.java.additional.36=-XX:+ExplicitGCInvokesConcurrent
wrapper.java.additional.37=-XX:CMSIncrementalSafetyFactor=20
wrapper.java.additional.38=-XX:+UseLargePages
wrapper.java.additional.39=-XX:-UseParallelGC
wrapper.java.additional.40=-XX:+CMSConcurrentMTEnabled
wrapper.java.additional.41=-XX:ConcGCThreads=4
wrapper.java.additional.42=-XX:ParallelGCThreads=12
wrapper.java.additional.43=-XX:MaxTenuringThreshold=10
wrapper.java.additional.44=-XX:InitialTenuringThreshold=10
```

So now I am trying to find the use of each parameter and if they deprecated or not.

Is there any documentation for this or anyone can hep me in this?

Comment: See [VM Options Explorer](https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_options_jdk8.html)

Comment: @apangin That did help. But not all the parameters are available there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/prop-java-additional-n.html) you have a great guide to what you need. There is A LOT of information, so you have to take a look and do some research, and [here](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-example-config.html) you have a list of properties.

Maybe all the parameters you need will not be available, but you can find the great part of them. [Here](https://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/props-advanced.html) is an advanced list, you can try to find more parameters.

As @apangin indicated [here](https://chriswhocodes.com/hotspot_option_differences.html) is a list of properties and their availability, or if they are deprecated, obsoleted or expired, version by version.

Finally, [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html) is an Oracle guide.

**Last but not least, if all of above is not enough, you can look [here](http://jvm-options.tech.xebia.fr/), where you can type and search what you need and even get a good example**